# Deleted attacks on the Shulchan Aruch in Pri Chadash

Tags: jewish-books

The bibliography in the English Me'am Lo'ez haggadah says of Pri Chadash that it "often strongly attacks the opinions of the Shulchan Aruch.  Its strongest language was deleted from later editions."  Does anyone know where these deleted parts can be found, or what they consisted of?

Comment: This idea that the Pri Chadash works were slightly toned down is mentioned by a few scholars. I guess your best bet is to get your hands on the first editions and compare and contrast to the Pri Chadash added to the Shulchan Aruch which is used today. Let us know your findings ,great question btw

Comment: Some quotes from the current uncensored version about other figures (can't imagine what the censored one had): About the Rashba: אמנם בשחיטה עצמה פשיטא שיש לאסור בקטן כסברת הרא"ה אף שיודע לאמן ידיו ויודע הלכות שחיטה ולא שייך בזה חזקה להתיר, ושרי ליה מאריה להרשב"א שהשיג על הרא"ה בזה וכתב שטעה טעות גדולה ונהפוך הוא שהדבר פשוט לאיסור וכמו שכתבתי לעיל בסימן א' ס"ק כ"ט, אלא שבאמת מרוב חפצו להשיג על הרא"ה בר פלוגתיה לא דייק במילתיה כולי האי.  About the Tur: ואל תשיבני מדברי הטור בנו לפי שהוא ז"ל נמשך אחר הרשב"א [תורת הבית הקצר ב"א ש"ב טז, א] ואחר פשט דברי הרא"ש בפסקיו ולא עיין בתשובת אביו

Comment: About S"A: ושרי ליה מאריה להב"י שאסר לנו את המותר דהיינו עוברים שחורים שאסרם בכל ענין, והתיר לנו את האסור דהיינו עוברים אדומים שהתירם בכל גוונא, ולא ביש לי דאמר הרב על טהור טמא אלא דאמר על טמא טהור.  About the Bach: והב"ח ז"ל [ד"ה העם] נמשך בזה באריכות דברים ושרי ליה מאריה שכתב פירושים זרים על גירסאות משובשות שנזדמנו לפניו ולפני הטור About Rashi: ולדינא לא קיימא לן כותיה דרש"י חדא שאין דבריו מחוורים, ועוד שכל הפוסקים חלוקים עליו, ועוד שאף לרש"י גופיה נמצא הפך זה ואיכא למימר דההיא בילדותו שנאה לנו

Comment: About Issur Veheter, and others: ודלא כהאיסור והיתר הארוך שדבריו מעורבבים בדין זה וטעה בהוראה זו וגרם טעות להג"ה ושאר אחרונים שנמשכו אחריו ולא עיינו ושגו ברואה וטעו בפשוטות About Maharshal: והוא דרך עיקש שומר נפשו ירחק ממנו שגם הוא נמשך אחר קבלת הראבי"ה, וכבר כתבנו שהוא טעות גמורה בידו וביד כל האומרים כן, הזה פועל חכם לסמוך אדם על סברת עצמו נגד כל הגדולים באיסורים דאורייתא, אלא שבאמת לא חיפש בספרים ולא ראה אותם.

Comment: ok can you please translate those רבות מחשבות

Comment: http://kotzkblog.blogspot.com/2018/01/161-ban-repeal-and-censoring-of-pri.html

Comment: @user16623  See Gemara Shabbos 96:2 תנו רבנן מקושש זה צלפחד ...דברי רבי עקיבא

The wood gatherer mentioned in the Torah was Zelophehad,  [said] Rabbi Akiva.
אמר לו רבי יהודה בן בתירא עקיבא ... אתה עתיד ליתן את הדין ... התורה כיסתו ואתה מגלה אותו -  Akiva, ... you will be judged...  for this teaching...  the Torah concealed his identity, and you reveal it: - So, dear OP unless you consider yourself equal to R' Akiva, why would you reveal that which the Torah scholars have concealed, [which may cast negativity on a great tzadik?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Do you mind citing which siman+seif-katan for those quotes? Also what version of the sefer do you have and do you know if its available online or in print?

Answer (score 6):

A related source: there's a teshuva in Ginas Veradim [yoreh deah klal 3, hilchos nedarim, shailah 3] about a person who moved to a new city. In the old city they had placed a cherem on learning the Pri Chadash's sefarim because of his sharp critiques of the Beis Yosef, and in the new city there was no ban and the shoel wanted to know if he could now learn the sefarim.

There's a modern edition of Shu"t Ginas Veradim with notes, and I seem to recall it having info about this topic. It might be worth checking it up. (I saw it years ago but I think it's relevant.)

Comment: Since you did not give the actual teshuvah this is only a comment.You should flag this and ask the moderator to move it into comments.

Comment: @sabbahillel thanks for the comment. I was able to look up the source and have edited my answer. I can't find the edition with the extensive notes that I saw before, but the teshuva itself is useful. Do you still think I should ask the moderator to move it to comments, or could it stand as a legit answer? (I'm still getting used to the forum and figuring out how to properly categorize things.) Thanks!

Comment: You should summarize the actual answer. That way people can see what you are actually answering. However, the question does not involve the ban but asks what is actually said and where the censored parts can be found. As a result your post does not answer the actual question.

Comment: @sabbahillel thanks for this feedback. When I can access the teshuva again I'll copy some of the language of the Pri Chadash which the Ginas Veradim quotes. He quotes some language and paraphrases  more, such that you can understand what the language was used.