# Was there any opposition to the Shulchan Aruch's methodology among the Sephardic Poskim?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, shulchan-aruch

I am aware of opposition to the Shulchan Aruch's methodology of paskening two out of three (Rif, Rambam and Rosh) from some Ashkenazic poskim of the time (namely the Masharshal). Was there any opposition among the Sephardic poskim of the time?

Comment: FWIW, the Shulchan Aruch writes that the kapparot ritual is silly and should be discontinued, while a number of Sephardim continue to do it every Erev Yom Kippur.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about opposition to the methodology you mentioned, or are you asking about any kind of opposition?

Comment: somewhat slightly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88863/deleted-attacks-on-the-shulchan-aruch-in-pri-chadash